# Eclipse cannot find main class

Tags: eclipse, java

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 with OpenJDk 7 installed

java -version gives

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

And whenever I try to run a  project, I'm getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/Example
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Example
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: test.Example. Program will exit.
```

This happens for all the projects, which I have compiled successfully on my Windows system.
And, when using the javac and java directly from the terminal, it works. 
Is there an easy solution? Is this because of OpenJDK?

The class code is :

```
package test;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Example() {
       setTitle("Simple example");
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Example ex = new Example();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

UPDATE: My source is in a folder called swingtest. While debugging, I found that Eclipse is using the classpath of the source as swingtest/swingtest/src/test/ rather than swingtest/src/test/ . Can this be corrected?

Comment: try to do a Project->clean and then build workspace and run again.

Comment: is parseProfile the class you are running? if so please post its code.

Comment: Does your class really not have a package?

Comment: @zengr I did try cleaning the project. But it didnt work

Comment: @ftom2 yes, it is the class i'm running

Comment: @JonSkeet i was trying to see if the package was the problem. I tried it with the package too, but still no luck

Comment: @rahules: You say it's a problem when you try to *build* it - but it looks like you're trying to *run* it. Which is it, and what *exactly* are you doing?

Comment: @ftom2 I'm not posting the parseProfile code as it's pretty big. This one doesn't work too. It's a class called Example, which when compiled through terminal works fine. But throws the errors (updated in the post) when done using eclipse

Comment: Is there only one build involved? This could be a classpath problem.

Comment: @Hbcdev Yes, I'm building only this project, just this one class. And it does seem to be  a classpath problem. Please see my last update in the main post.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, it happens when i try to run it. Corrected in the post

Comment: How did you exported the project from Windows and then imported back in Linux? I am sure it is not a problem of Eclipse on Linux platform. It can be due to compile or build path errors. When you add jars in eclipse build path it uses full file system path to the file not the relative path. So while moving the project across platforms, we usually get this type of errors. For this you can look into .classpath file of your project if it contains any absolute path to a dependency. Also, you can always change the source folder by editing the Build Path from context menu of the project explorer.

Comment: @vikas thanks for mentioning that. I tried creating a new workspace and it's working fine. I think a ':' in my path was the problem

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur because of below reason

1. Might be missing a dependency/Required jar.
   To find if the jar is missing click on project->Java Build Path->source
   at the top you can see a error message xyz.jar is missing.
   So add that particular jar by clicking add external jars option
2. May be java classpath is not set.
   So configure the JDK classpath both in eclipse and also environmental setup
3. Try to clean the project and see if its rectified

Answer (score -1):

Right-click your project and select Build Path > Configure Build Path. click the source tab and select Add Folder. then point it to your swingtest folder. you can delete the current default that eclipse is using

Comment: It turned out that eclipse had some problems with my worskpace. Changed the workspace and it is working fine.